# c++ SDL - Render inside a window's particular area

Tags: c++, canvas, sdl, area, renderer

I want to align my game components like an HTML game.

My `SDL_Window`will have a `SDL_Renderer`rendering all of his components. These components are some buttons, images and a rectangle area **like an html canvas**.

I want my game to be rendered **inside this canvas**, because I will implement a "world" and a "camera" which will affect only this "canvas", while the GUI around the "canvas" will be rendered independently of the camera.

**How to have a renderer rendering a particular area inside of a window?**

I can't do this with mathematics, because I want every texture rendered inside the canvas, but too far from the point of view, to be hidden.

Part of the code:

```
    SDL_Window* gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    while (true) {
        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
        render_gui(); // i can do this part
        render_game_inside_canvas(); // ?
        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Kindly show at least a minimal effort to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with glViewport() call like this:

```
Point2d pos = get_pos();
Vector2d sz = get_size();
glViewport(pos.x, screen_height-pos.y-sz.dy, sz.dx, sz.dy);
obj.render();
glViewport(0,0,screen_width, screen_height);
```

It kinda requires you to know what is the dimensions of your whole screen...
(the odd calculation is required because glViewport keeps the screen upsidedown :-)